# illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown filter type [phonetic] for [phonetic]

Tags: elasticsearch, version, magento2, phonetics

I got an error in the elastic search indexer module.i have installed elasticsearch version 7.9 with magento2.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown filter type [phonetic] for [phonetic]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown filter type [phonetic] for [phonetic]"},"status":400}
```

how can i fix this issue ??

Comment: are you defining a new analyzer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the elasticsearch configuration, the plugin is required, try this out!

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Then try reindexing again.

Answer (score 1):

Eelastic Suite requires these commands to be run

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic

sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu

sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Comment: More infos: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/ServerConfig-5.x#installing-required-plugins

Answer (score 1):

Your elastic search is missing a plugin.
This problem occurred to me during reindexing after the elastic version was upgraded from 7.9.2 (log4j) to 7.17.9.
I fixed it by installing the necessary plugins.

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

This issue has already been closed on the Smile ElasticSuite - Magento 2 GitHub.
cc: ramindas

find more about phonetic analysis plugin : [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should install the phonetic plugin ([Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html))

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time, this issue is faced when elastic search version is incompatible with your working platform. Here your Magento version might be incompatible with the version of elasticsearch.
To test your elastic search version:

```
curl localhost:9200
```

Change your e.s version accordingly

Comment: this particular error is not relative to the version, the plugins are missing and that is answered already.